# Create a dictionary (map) with string, index in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['a','b','a','c','d','b','e'])
```

I want to create a map(dictionary) of each unique value to an index.

The output will be a **map (key, value)** like:

```
{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2,'d':3,'e':4}
```

It's super easy to do in Python but I don't know how to do this in Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [zipWithIndex](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=zipwithindex#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex)

So for your example (The "sort" part is only to get a to be 0 and so on):

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['a','b','a','c','d','b','e'])

print rdd.distinct().sortBy(lambda x: x).zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
```

> {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3}

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept gaps this should do the trick:

```py
rdd.zipWithIndex().reduceByKey(min).collectAsMap()
# {'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'a': 0, 'e': 6, 'd': 4}
```

Otherwise (much more expensive)

```py
(rdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .reduceByKey(min)
    .sortBy(lambda x: x[1])
    .keys()
    .zipWithIndex()
    .collectAsMap())
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4}
```

Comment: this looks fine. but what do you mean by gaps?

Comment: The first solution behaves like sparse rank, the second (which gives the result you seem to expect), more like dense rank (note that `e` is mapped to 6 - index in the original input, not 4 - index in RDD after dropping duplicates).